# How to return object from a DQL query?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, dql

I have written a DQL query in Doctrine 2:

```
$qb->select('r.position')
    ->from('\Entities\Races', 'r')
    ->where($qb->expr()->eq('r.entrantId', ':entrant_id'))
    ->setParameter('entrant_id', $this->entrantId);
$query = $qb->getQuery();
$aRaces = $query->getResult();
```

Currently it returns the results of the query in an array like so:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [position] => 10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [position] => 4
        )
)
```

I want the result to return an array of Races **objects** so that I can access the methods associated with the object (I'm pretty sure the previous version of Doctrine returned objects by default).

I tried:

```
$aRaces = $query->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_OBJECT);
```

But that didn't make a difference.

Appreciate the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are fetching only `position` column from DB. Try replacing `select('r.position')` with `select(r)`. See [DQL reference](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html)

If you need objects with only `position` attribute, refer to [partial objects](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/partial-objects.html)

Answer (score 3):

The: `$qb->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_OBJECT);`

Return an array with object and you can catch them with: `$match[0];`

If you want to return a single result you must be use: `$qb->getOneOrNullResult()`

Answer (score 1):

I could not solve my problem with your solution, here my part of code:

```
$qb = $this->_objectManager->createQuery('Select d from Hotbed\Entity\Department d where d.id <> :id and d.title = :title');
        $qb->setParameters(array('id' => $context['id'], 'title' => $value));
        $match = $qb->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_OBJECT);
```

$match returns this:

```
array(1) {
 [0] => object(Hotbed\Entity\Department)#626 (4) {
   ['inputFilter':protected] =&gt; NULL
   ['id':protected] =&gt; int(25)
   ['title':protected] => string(4) '2222'
   ['state':protected] => int(0)
 }
}
```

thx for any help