# Order by multiple columns value with Doctrine

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to find a way to sort data, with symfony2 and doctrine, based on minimum values in two columns, something like.

```
$em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$test = $em->createQuery('select t from AcmeBundle:Test t where t.name is not null order by t.price1, t.price2')->getResult();
```

The thing is that doing it this way sorts first by `price1` and after by `price2`.

Is there a way to make it sort by min value in `price1` and `price2`, combined, not separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select and order by min value of collumns `price` and `price1`:

```
$test = $em->createQuery('select b, CASE WHEN (price1 > price) THEN price ELSE price1 END as order_value from AcmeBundle:Test t where t.name is not null order by order_value')->getResult();
```

Comment: not exactly, I need it sorted by min value which can be in price1 or price2, it doesn't matter in which one.

Comment: thanks for the quick replay, but when I do that I get: [Syntax Error]: Error: Expected known function, got 'IF'

Comment: Ok, so let's try `CASE WHEN` instead of `IF`. I updated my answer.

Comment: that did the trick, only problem is that now I get results as an multidimensional array, but actually I need result as an array of objects. Do you, maybe, know if there is a way to overcome this situation.

Comment: Use `getArrayResult()` instead of `getResult()` ; )

Comment: Well, that is opposite of what I need. I need "array of objects" not array of array

Comment: ok, I've found something that is response to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063926/how-to-return-object-from-a-dql-query, so I'll try with partial and see what happens